# How to combine aggregate results?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two queries:

Q#1:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Col1,
  COUNT(Col1) AS COUNT
FROM
  `dataset.W01_*`
GROUP BY
  Col1
ORDER BY
  COUNT DESC
```

Q#2:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Col1,
  COUNT(Col1) AS COUNT
FROM
  `dataset.W02_*`
GROUP BY
  Col1
ORDER BY
  COUNT DESC
```

With Results:

```
Result1     
Row Col1    COUNT
1   12345   33844
2   56789   32161
3   11223   31298
```

and

```
Result2     
Row Col1    COUNT
1   12345   33944
2   11223   41298
3   67890   12161
```

I want to combine the queries to get the following 
result:

```
Row Col1    COUNT
1   11223   41298
2   12345   33944
3   56789   32161
4   67890   12161
```

Basically in Result2:

1) 12345's count is bigger : 33944 than in Result1 
and I want it with the new count in the new table.

2) Col1=67890 is new and I want it with its COUNT
in the new table.

So the two results to be merged with updated new rows,
new counts and sorted by COUNT in decreasing order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH result1 AS (
  SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) AS count
  FROM `dataset.W01_*`
  GROUP BY Col1
), result2 AS (
  SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) AS count
  FROM `dataset.W02_*`
  GROUP BY Col1
)
SELECT col1, GREATEST(IFNULL(t1.count, t2.count), IFNULL(t2.count, t1.count)) count
FROM result1 t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN result2 t2
USING (col1)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Also, note: you do not need `DISTINCT` in your Q1 and Q2 queries

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer. The SQL is much neater/succinct/clearer, and +1 for dropping the need for the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: is there are possibility to do a query like this?

FROM `dataset_*.W01_*`

Comment: nope, i am not. and i am not affiliated. but i consider myself BigQuery expert (and I am official Google Developer Expert for Cloud Platform) and most importantly I love helping.

Comment: You are an expert definitely. Your answers are quick and on the point.

Comment: I have another problem with my databases - there is a lot of `dataset.W01_*`,`dataset.W02_*`...  ~100
Right now I have to write result1 , result2 - 100 times. Are there a way to simplify that?

Comment: you can minimize the number of resultN by using `dataset.W*` or if you need to be more precise you can use `dataset.W0*`, `dataset.W1*` etc. if this does not apply to your specific use case - please post new question with all details and we will be happy to help

Comment: The tables are like this: datasetW0.W0*, datasetW1.W1*